# DateTime doesnt allow hour values greater than 12

Tags: c#

I have this simple code:

```
DateTime endFinal = new DateTime(
  end.Year, 
  end.Month, 
  end.Day, 
  Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndHours), 
  Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndMinutes), 
  0);
```

If I enter an hour that is greater than `12`, it throws an invalid datetime error.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.'

What can I do to avoid it? I want to enter numbers greater than `12`.

How can I overcome that behavoir?

I am using that function inside web form web application.

Comment: Use the debugger and find what values are stored in that _hb_ variable.

Comment: So your problem is with numbers greater than 12 or 24? You are mentioning both...

Comment: Greater than 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't accept more than `24` hours, because - well - a day only has 24 hours.
You can use a `TimeSpan` to achieve what you want:

```
DateTime endFinal = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, end.Day)
         .Add(new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndHours), Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndMinutes), 0));
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I will test it now. BTW, it doesnt also accept numbers greater than 12.

Comment: I like your solution most.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `AddHours` (and, probably, `AddMinutes`):

```
   DateTime endFinal = new DateTime(
      end.Year, 
      end.Month, 
      end.Day, 
      0, 
      0, 
      0)
   .AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndHours))
   .AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(hb.EndMinutes));
```

Now `hb.EndHours` can be of any integer value (over `24` or less than `0`),

**Edit**: Test (see comments below):

```
  DateTime endFinal = new DateTime(
    2017,
       4,
      17,
       0,
       0,
       0)
    .AddHours(13)
    .AddMinutes(50);

  Console.Write(endFinal.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Outcome:

```
  17-04-2017 13:50:00
```

Comment: Sometimes i'm overcomplicating things, nice :)

Comment: add hours doesnt work. if I add 13 hours.. I get a value of 0 in the hour field. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @dan mann: please, check output/representation. I've added test with `13` hours

Comment: Could it be the fault of the way that my computer is set?

Comment: @dan mann: Could you, please, provide the code extract? How do you represent/print out the `endFinal`?

Comment: I think your code is fine. I have no idea why I started receiving an error when inputing an hour value greater than 12.